# How to duplicate a list item in the same list in O365

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a provider hosted SharePoint app. 
I need to add a custom action item "copy" in the context menu of a list item. 
On click of copy I should get a duplicate of that item at the bottom in the same list in SharePoint online. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can create a workflow using sharepont designer to copy item and then use that workflow as custom action.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have to do it without workflow

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution:

```
// get the file
                File file = sourceItem.File;
                clientContext.Load(file);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                char[] chars = { '.' };
                var fileName = file.Name.Split(chars);
                // build destination url
                string locationUrl = web.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + destinationList.Title + "/" + fileName[0] + "-Copy." + fileName[1];

                // read the file, copy the content to new file at new location
                file.CopyTo(locationUrl, true);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

The above code would do the work !